# Why does tkinter crash when i try using the keyboard module?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

Whenever i try to make the keyboard module type something when a tkinter button is clicked, it starts lagging a lot, resulting in the tkinter window getting the "application not responding" error.

What i tried to make is a program that spams anything you write in the textbox after you click the "spam" button.

Here is my python code:

```
# imports
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard as kb


# setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Autospam by previous")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg="black")
stopspam = False


# functions
def start():
    stopspam = False
    while True:
        kb.write(entry1.get(), 0.1)  # 0.1 delay prevents massive lag
        if stopspam is True:
            break


def stop():
    stopspam = True


# design
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Autospam", font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"), bg="black", fg="white")
label1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Made by previous", font=("Verdana", 15, "italic"), bg="black", fg="white")
label2.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.15)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text="text:", font=("Verdana", 15), bg="black", fg="white")
label3.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.3)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, font=("Verdana", 15, "bold"))
entry1.place(relx=0.125, rely=0.4)

label4 = tk.Label(root, text="tip: don't use large chunks of text.", font=("Verdana", 15), bg="black", fg="white")
label4.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.5)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Spam", font=("Verdana", 15, "bold"), command=start)
button1.place(relx=0.125, rely=0.8)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", font=("Verdana", 15, "bold"), command=stop)
button2.place(relx=0.525, rely=0.8)


# mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

If there are any other mistakes or errors i've missed, feel free to say them!

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your program is single-threaded**, so the `while True` loop in `start()` causes the `root.mainloop()` to not run, thus the window does not respond. To fix this, we'll use a recursive function defined with tkinter's built-in function `.after()`.

```
# functions
def start():
    global stopspam
    stopspam = False
    toWrite = entry1.get()
    
    loop(toWrite)

def loop(text):
    if not stopspam:
        kb.write(text, 0.1)
        root.after(10, loop, text) #run again after 10 milliseconds

def stop():
    global stopspam
    stopspam = True
```

The `global` declarations are required because you are modifying a variable inside of a method. Notice how it's not necessary inside of the `loop` method.

Your program was also going to be *very* slow because you were running `entry1.get()` in every `kb.write` instance. So it would exponentially get slower and slower, since the `keyboard.write()` is slow once strings get large. I modified the code to only write your initial string, which is probably what you were intending in the first place.

**Hope this helps!**